# How to define a dynamic array in Simulink using MATLAB function and Model Explorer

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink

I am working on a MATLAB Simulink design and I am stucked on a problem. I would like to create a an dynamic uint8 array whose length is random. To do this, I have created a Matlab function and defined the variable as:

```
len = 100;
ethMesg = ones([1,len], 'uint8');
```

Note: Len is going to a random integer in future.

Later, I have opened the Model Explorer and set it as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69e85.png)

So, basically I checked the Variable size box and set a limit as 1 to 1514 (1x1514) because MATLAB Simulink asks for an upper limit. When I try to build the model (CTRL + D) the error below returns.

> Expression '[1 1514]' for maximum of data 'ethMesg' must evaluate to a
> scalar.

I think Simulink thinks this variable as a scalar and does not acccept a vector definition in Model Explorer (1 x 1514). Does anyone knows how to make sure that a variable is defined as a vector, or am I doing something wrong because this variable makes problem for the last 2 days.

Btw, do I have to check the "varied size" box to define a varied variable because otherwise Simulink asks for a specific size?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112235-variable-size-matrix-error-in-matlab-function-block

Here it says maximum value must be defined in size block rather than Min-Max limit.
Though my problem is solved, I still could not understand the purpose of Min-Max values. Maybe it is used for defining the limits of a particular uint8.